# Which package to install to run this code successfully

Tags: haskell, package, cabal

I am trying following simple code from [here](https://haskell-at-work.com/episodes/2018-11-13-gtk-programming-with-haskell.html) :

```
import Data.GI.Base
import qualified GI.Gtk as Gtk

main :: IO()
main = do
  Gtk.init Nothing
  Gtk.main
```

However, I am getting following error:

```
    Could not find module `Data.GI.Base'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
1 | import Data.GI.Base
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

simplewin.hs:2:1: error:
    Could not find module `GI.Gtk'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
2 | import qualified GI.Gtk as Gtk
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Following attempts to install packages do not find any matches:

```
>cabal list Data.GI.Base
No matches found.

>cabal list GI.Gtk
No matches found.
```

Which packages do I install with cabal to correct above errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org) (the FPComplete package repository, the de-facto standard for Haskell) for the module, type, or function name.

For example, when I type in `Data.GI.Base`, I get [its documentation page](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.5/haskell-gi-base-0.23.0/Data-GI-Base.html), which tells me (at the very top) that the module is available in the package `haskell-gi-base`.

Not every package is available on Stackage though. If you can't find something, try [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/) next. It's less regulated and controlled, but has more stuff because of it.

Comment: Actually @rnso, you’re better off installing `gi-gtk` rather than `haskell-gi-base` here, as that’s where `GI.Gtk` comes from.  Installation of this library can be a bit tricky though; for more information see https://github.com/haskell-gi/haskell-gi#installation.